# Magento 2 - Custom registration and login with external system

Tags: magento2, customer, login, register

I have an external system that stores all the customer accounts. I need to integrate it with Magento so that when a user logins or registers, Magento calls a API of the external system to do the registration and authentication. Which classes should I override or modify to achieve this?

Comment: Did you do this? I have a similar scenario here.